# Kieran Healy's emacs starter kit in linux (fedora19): "/bin/bash: osascript: command not found" message

Tags: linux, git, emacs, fedora

I am user of Kieran Healy's Emacs Starter Kit. I have run it on the Fedora distro of Linux for around a year or so.  Things have always run smoothly, but now that I have upgraded from Fedora17 to Fedora19, when I  try to commit in Magit, I get the following message: /bin/bash: osascript: command not found

I understand I get this message because Kieran customizes  the ESSK for the Mac OS. So I thought I just needed to tweak this feature. To do that, I need to find where in the emacs dot files is the call to an osascript, but when I use Grep to find the string 'osascript', I get no match.

Hence my question: does anyone know where in the emacs dot files there is a call to an  osascript for the  commit command in git to run?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report for Emacs Starter Kit than a general programming question. Have you contacted Kieran Healy directly?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on a current version of the starter kit:  http://kieranhealy.org/resources/emacs-starter-kit.html

```
MP:~ HOME$ grep -inIEr --color=ALWAYS -C1 "osascript" .../emacs-starter-kit-master
.../emacs-starter-kit-master/kjhealy.org-189-    (defun raise-emacs-on-aqua()
.../emacs-starter-kit-master/kjhealy.org:190:    (shell-command "osascript -e 'tell application \"Emacs\" to activate' &"))
.../emacs-starter-kit-master/kjhealy.org-191-    (add-hook 'server-switch-hook 'raise-emacs-on-aqua)
MP:~ HOME$
```

Comment: You are right, I was using grep without the -R option and that is why I could not see these lines where Kieran Healy is fine-tuning the default pdf viewer in Mac OS. Thanks for that. However, I still do not understand what this invokation of "osascript" in connection with the skim pdf viewer has to do with Magit, one of emacs' way  for interacting with Git.

Comment: `osascript` is a program built into OSX to tell other OSX programs what to do (e.g., open, close, do the hokey pokey and turn around, etc.).  If you are not using OSX, then that would be a problem causing the shell-command to fail.  You could change the function `raise-emacs-on-aqua` so that it doesn't call a program that does not exist on your operating system.  You could also remove the `server-switch-hook`.

Comment: Right: commenting out the function raise-emacs-on-aqua solves the problem. It also helps noticing that whereas before this upgrade the key binding for committing after you wrote the commit message was C-c C-c, now you have to binding is C-x #. Thank you Lawlist